# A doubt about series involving geometric progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Assume that $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is a variable and $\alpha \in (0,1)$ is a constant and $\Lambda$ and $m \in \mathbb{N}$ are defined such that:
\begin{align*}
\Lambda=\max \{n, \frac{1}{1-\alpha}\log \frac{1}{1-\alpha}\}, \quad 0 \leq m \leq n.
\end{align*}
We can assume that $m$ is fixed. I want to show that 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{l > \Lambda} l^2 \alpha^{4(l+m-1-n)}= O_n(1).
\end{align*}
By $O_n(1)$ I mean that the constant in $O(1)$ is not dependent on $n$. What would be a natural way to solve this problem?

My attempt:
$\sum_{l > \Lambda} l^2 \alpha^{4(l+m-1-n)} = \sum_{l > \Lambda} \alpha^{4(m-n-1)} \alpha^{4l + \frac{\log l}{\log \alpha} } = \sum_{l > \Lambda} \alpha^{4(m-n-1)} \alpha^{O(\frac{4 l}{\log \alpha} )} $. I don't see a simplification from this point.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to prove is not true if is $m$ fixed.

Let $n$ be big enough that $\Lambda = n$. Then we have

$$\sum_{l > \Lambda} l^2 \alpha^{4(l+m-1-n)}= \sum_{l =n+1}^\infty l^2 \alpha^{4(l+m-1-n)} \ge (n+1)^2 \alpha^{4((n+1)+m-1-n)} = (n+1)^2 \alpha^{4m}.$$

The inequality holds because the sum has only non-negative summands and we just took the first. If $m$ is fixed, then the sum is bound below by a constant times $n^2$, which is not $O(1)$.

If $m$ is not fixed, then it depends on what we know about $m$. If we know nothing, then it could be fixed, so your assertion is not true.

If $m$ can always be equal to $n$ (the 'best case' in which the sum gets as small as possible), we have

$$\sum_{l > \Lambda} l^2 \alpha^{4(l+m-1-n)} = \sum_{l > \Lambda} l^2 \alpha^{4(l-1)} \le \sum_{l =1}^\infty l^2 \alpha^{4(l-1)}.$$

Since $\frac1\alpha > 1$, the function $\frac1\alpha^l$ increases faster than $l^2$, that means we have some $L_0$ such that $\frac1\alpha^l > l^2$ if $l > L_0$. That means

$$\sum_{l =1}^\infty l^2 \alpha^{4(l-1)} = \sum_{l=1}^{L_0} l^2 \alpha^{4(l-1)} + \sum_{l =L_0+1}^\infty l^2 \alpha^{4(l-1)} \le \sum_{l=1}^{L_0} l^2 \alpha^{4(l-1)} + \sum_{l =L_0+1}^\infty \alpha^{-1} \alpha^{4(l-1)} = \sum_{l=1}^{L_0} l^2 \alpha^{4(l-1)} + \alpha^{-5}\sum_{l =L_0+1}^\infty \alpha^{4l}.$$

The first sum on the right hand side contains finitely many summands, so is finite ($L_0$ does not depend on $n$). The second is part of an infinite geometric series with quotient $\alpha^4 < 1$, so it is also finite.

Maybe somebody else can give results if $m$ varies in a different way depending on $n$.